# A couple questions about REST

Tags: rest

I have two questions about REST

1) Should I always try to avoid sending input data when using REST? Should all my requests try to pass most data possible through the uri and not through post?

2) Which of the two formats below is more "RESTful"?

/tasks/delete/{task_id}

or

/tasks/{task_id}/delete/

Comment: For your second question, neither is "RESTful" - you should have `/tasks/{id}` called with an HTTP DELETE call.

Comment: I know it is sometimes difficult to suggest books, but I read a small one which is just about 100 pages long and it answer this kind of questions quite easily: REST API Design Rulebook from OReilly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Should I always try to avoid sending input data when using REST? Should all my requests try to pass most data possible through the uri and not through post?

If you POST a large resource, that's fine. If you need to do a GET conceptually, but turn that into a POST so that you can encode the GET parameters in the request body, then that conflicts with REST.

> 2) Which of the two formats below is more "RESTful"?

Neither `/tasks/delete/{task_id}` nor `/tasks/{task_id}/delete` is correct. "delete" is a verb, but the URL should be a noun. If you want to delete a task, use `DELETE /tasks/{task_id}`, rather than somthing like `POST /tasks/{task_id}/delete`.